# public function returns NULL instead of array

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to write a thin wrapper around pdo mysql, but I am running into an issue where a public function is returning null instead of the expected array of associative arrays. Is this a problem with pass by value/reference? My initial thought was this was a reference or public issue, but the trivial example works.

```
<?php
class PDOMysqlAdapter {
  public $db;
  public $result;
  public $test = array(1,2);

  public function get(){
    return $this->test;
  }

  public function __construct($host, $port, $dbname, $username, $password, $charset = "utf8") {
    $this->db = new PDO(
      "mysql:host={$host};port={$port};dbname={$dbname};charset={$charset}",
      $username,
      $password
    );
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }

  public function singleton($sql, $debug = false) {
    if($debug) { error_log("Executing:\n\n{$sql}\n"); }

    try {
      $this->result = $this->db->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if($debug) { error_log(print_r($this->result, true)); }
      return $this->result;
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
      error_log($ex->getMessage()."\n");
      return NULL;
    }
  }

  public function multiple($sql, $debug = false) {
    if($debug) { error_log("Executing:\n\n{$sql}\n"); }

    try {
      $this->result = $this->db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if($debug) { error_log(print_r($this->result, true)); }
      error_log(count($this->result));
      return $this->result;
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
      error_log($ex->getMessage()."\n");
      return NULL;
    }
  }
}

$db = new PDOMysqlAdapter(DB_SERVER, DB_PORT, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

error_log(print_r($db->get(), true)); // does what I think it should

$result = $db->singleton("SELECT 1", true);
error_log(print_r($result, true));  // return { '1' => '1' }

$foo = $db->multiple("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 2", true); // query returns without error and result exists within scope
error_log(print_r($foo, true));  // null
error_log(count($db->result));   // variable is public and full of expected contents
```

Why is $foo NULL here? `$db->result` contains the things that I expect to be returned into $foo.

Comment: `singleton` is the improper use of the word, just saying.

Comment: You're quite certain there's no PDOException? It you put `return 'oops'` instead of `return NULL` what happens?

Comment: @Jerry return 'oops' (in the catch) has the same output, when I error_log  the $db->result, I see the array has been populated from sql. I can even see the array, while inside the try, but it is like it never makes it out of the functional scope.

Comment: Dang, I'm not sure what to tell you - I copied and pasted your code and after I tweaked the database details it worked just fine for me.

Comment: You've got all this output (like `error_log()` 78 times over) but you don't tell us what code is executing. Does the `catch` statement get executed? What shows up in your error log? I suspect you've got a typo somewhere...

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for the feedback. Since it works on someone elses machine, I think this boils down to some environment, or php.ini, or other factor.